# Outputting full name in query powershell

Tags: powershell, query

I am querying a sharepoint site. At the moment its returning `Our future comm...`
how would I be able to make it print out the full name
Here is my code

```
Get-SPSite mysite |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Select -ExpandProperty Items |
Select Name, Scope, Column1 | Out-File test.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Out-String](http://poshoholic.com/2010/11/11/powershell-quick-tip-creating-wide-tables-with-powershell/) can increase the window character limit.

```
"long string" | Out-String width 4096 | Out-File test.txt
```

I don't know if it is the best option, but it is an option.